# How can I determine USB host controller type

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

I'm trying to determine wheter my tablets have:

- Open Host Controller Interface (OHCI)
- Universal Host Controller Interface (UHCI)
- Ehanced Host Controller Interface (EHCI)

Is there any tool that could help me to determine it?
My tablets are:

- Samsung GT P3110
- GoClever R76.2

Comment: I can't find an answer myself, I guess my Googlefu isn't strong enough. Might it be easier to contact the OEMs directly and ask them? Don't forget to post an answer here if you get one!

Comment: on terminal emulator or adb: "pm list features | grep usb" should give you android.hardware.usb.host if that feature is available. I don't know about the other details.

Answer (score 0):

I was told i would not have permissions to comment here?!? Therefore here my comment.

Perhaps you could have a look on what additional cables are available for your device. If you want it to be usb master there's a universal cable that works well. But if you want hdmi connection, make sure you take a samsung adapter for your samsung device, the standardized version won't work, samsung has it's own protocol there.